# Refs for Ps. 119 being called "Alfa-Bita" and "Temanya Apin"?

Tags: tehilim-psalms

Can someone provide a citation (sefer, page if possible) for Ps. 119 having the monikers "Alfa-Bita" and "Temanya Apei" (=Eight Faces)?

I've seen it called Alfa Bita I think somewhere in BIH or a Sefardi Siddur, Temanya is a new one to me.

These claims are written stam in the Hebrew Wikipedia article
https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%22%D7%98

> נקרא גם תְּמַנְיָא אַפֵּי (בארמית: שמונָה פנים) או אלפא ביתא על שם מבנה

I tried to add to the en: site but was reverted, requires citation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalm_119

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Psalm 119 is referred to as *temanya apin* in [Berachot 4b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.4b.18?lang=bi):

> אִילֵּימָא מִשּׁוּם דְּאָתְיָא בְּאָלֶף בֵּית, נֵימָא ״אַשְׁרֵי תְמִימֵי דָרֶךְ״ דְּאָתְיָא בִּתְמָנְיָא אַפִּין

It is referred to as *alfa beta* by R. Shlomo Alkabetz (quoted by Shelah [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Aseret_HaDibrot%2C_Shevuot%2C_Ner_Mitzva.13?vhe=Shenei_Luchot_HaBrit,_based_on_Amsterdam,_1698_ed._Part_II&lang=he)) where he lists the texts that were recited as part of *tikkun leil shavuot*:

> אח"כ (תהילים י״ט:ב׳) מזמור השמים מספרים, ומזמור יקום אלקים (שם סח). אח"כ האלפא ביתא (שם קיט) בלא השירות (מפרק קכ).‏